# What Javascript Regular Expression features are unique to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I hope this question isn't too broad, but then again I would expect the Javascript (and other languages) regular expression engine's to share most of it's functionality with what is considered standard / expected regular expression behavior.

I made a statement about C# having unique regular expression capabilities in this post :: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7564061/590956)

Specifically, here is the statement:

> C# is unique when it comes to regular expressions in that it supports
>   [Balancing Group
>   Definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition).
>
> - See [Matching Balanced Constructs with .NET Regular Expressions](http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2005/02/20/377025.aspx)
> - See [.NET Regular Expressions: Regex and Balanced Matching](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396452.aspx)
> - See Microsoft's docs on [Balancing Group Definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition)

I'm curious what unique regular expression capabilities javascript has if any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although JavaScript’s regular expression library supports features that are considered as common (see [comparison table](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html)), there is one particular expression that I haven’t seen in other:

```
/[^]/
```

This matches any arbitrary character similar to `/[\s\S]/` (or any other union of complementary character classes) and can be handy as JavaScript does not have a *s* modifier like others have to have `.` match line breaks too.

Similar to that:

```
/[]/
```

This evaluates to an empty character set and can’t match anything at all.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript's regex engine is merely a subset of Perl's engine, meaning that it doesn't add anything new and is missing many of the features Perl contains.

You can read more about it here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html.

Answer (score 2):

javascript regexes are a subset of perl regexes.
Meaning, it has no unique features, but it's missing quite a few.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript regular expressions are modeled on Perl's regular expressions.

See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html